# How to check if two template parameters are exactly the same?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

*How do I modify the following function template so that it returns 42 if template parameters `T` and `U` are exactly the same type?*

```
template<typename T,typename U>
int Foo()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just us [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) inside the function with an if statement.

Comment: You can't partially specialise function templates (but don't ask why).

Comment: @ipc +1 OP changed: you're right - it was a bad choice of words

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) can provide the desired behaviour:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,typename U>
int Foo()
{
    return std::is_same<T, U>::value ? 42 : 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a specialization though

Comment: @AxelGneiting, agreed but it provides the desired behaviour. I may be mistaken but I though it was not possible to provide a function template specialization (they can be overloaded).

Comment: The example implementation linked is quite instructive.

Comment: @AndyProwl, will add that though it is stated in the linked reference page. Ta.

Comment: worked great - quick question: since it's a compile-time construct, it is cheap (false blocks will be optimised out?), right?  I may have to use it several times, in a switch-like fashion...

Comment: +1 this easy enough for `is_same<T, U>::value` but for more difficult compile-time conditions, I prefer a partial class specialization in as a helper class

Comment: Anybody know if the `std` allows you to extend `is_same<T, U>`?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain you can only add full specialization to namespace std, not partial ones or new function overloads. But even that is frowned upon (see the tons of std::swap questions here)

Comment: There's a special rule that forbids to specialize the templates from `<type_traits>`.

Answer (score 7):

An idiomatic way is to delegate the work to a helper function object in a `detail` namespace that you can partially specialize for the case where `T` is the same as `U` (or for any other compile-time pattern that you can use in class templates).

```
namespace detail {

template<typename T, typename U>
struct foo
{
     int operator()() const
     {
         return 0;
     }
};

template<typename T>
struct foo<T, T>
{
     int operator()() const
     {
         return 42;
     }
};

} // namespace detail 

template<typename T, typename U>
int Foo()
{
     return detail::foo<T, U>()();
}
```

For functions which also have deducible arguments (e.g. a `Foo(T x, U y)` would) this combines the power of argument deduction of function templates, and the specialization capabilities of class templates, without users every being the wiser (well, you need the convention that they do not call anything from `namespace detail` directly)

Comment: +1 I have used a similar approach before but must admit I couldn't see past `std::is_same` when it entered my head.

Comment: @hmjd once `static_if` becomes a reality, your solution would be the new idiomatic solution!

Comment: I wouldn't call this idiomatic (or maybe I'm just behind the times), I find overloads on `std::true_type`/`std::false_type` much easier to manage. Also, you can make those functions static.

Comment: despite the ugly `operator()()` syntax, iirc, this method also has the added benefit of allowing us to return a different type: eg `std::string operator()() { return "foo"; }` - will go try that out now.

Comment: @GManNickG It's Item 66 of Sutter & Alexandrescu's Coding Standards: "If you're writing a function template, prefer to write it as a single function template that should never be specialized or overloaded, and implement the function template entirely in terms of a class template. This is the proverbial extra level of indirection
that steers you well clear of the limitations and dark corners of function templates." THat book is dated 2005, so not sure if that's no longer idiomatic ;-)

Comment: @rhalbersma: Maybe. :) I've posted my answer for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness in the answers, here's how you can make this choice at compile-time without classes:

```
namespace detail
{
    int Foo(std::true_type)
    {
        return 42;
    }

    int Foo(std::false_type)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

template <typename T, typename U>
int Foo()
{
    return detail::Foo(std::is_same<T, U>());
}
```

This compile-time branching is important when the two different code paths have different requirements on your arguments (none in this case, though). For example, in one path you use member function `x()` and in the other `y()`; or as you've noted, even entirely "different" functions.

This, to me, is much simpler than managing a class.

Comment: +1 you want `return 0;` for the `false_type` though. BTW, you are still using a class `std::is_same` but you are not managing it: your  Standard Library author is (a good thing!). For more complicated patterns (`U` equal to `T*` or something like that), the corresponding type trait might be more difficult to write than the class specialization.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Oops, thanks. Yup, though the `type_traits` header is pretty rich. For your example, though, no big changes: `std::is_equal<U, T*>`.

Comment: +1 nice example - I strongly prefer simplicity (didn't know about std::true_type/std::false_type!)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T,typename U>
struct Foo {
  int operator()()
  {
    return 0;
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, T> {
  int operator()()
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

int main() {
   std::cout << Foo<int, int>()() << std::endl;
   std::cout << Foo<int, double>()() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ha, see my answer 2 minutes ago ;-)

Comment: @rhalbersma Snap... though your version is slightly nicer syntactically.