# Testing template parameter for equality

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a template class defined as:

```
template < typename A, typename B >
class something { ... }
```

How can I test if types A and B are of the same type? I know this can be done at runtime with typeid, but I really need this to be a compile time test.

Also, How can I specialize the class if types A and B are equal?

In the real world, A would be an stl container of some sort, std::string for example, and B would be a char or wchar_t. Internally I already check the containers value_type (compile error if not what expected). If B is the same as the containers value_type, most of the code in the class will become redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if two template parameters are exactly the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635413/how-to-check-if-two-template-parameters-are-exactly-the-same)

Comment: @hmjd Similar question, different answer.

Comment: @hmjd: There is a similar question AND a non-similar one. This question asks too much, actually.

Comment: @hmjd Thanks for the link. I hate the search feature on this site.

Comment: @Waldermort: you can also type "site:stackoverflow.com <your query>" into google. You can even make that a simple shortcut in firefox (right click on any inputbox and use "add keyword for this search").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also, How can I specialize the class if types A and B are equal?

By exactly that, specializing:

```
template <typename A>
class something<A,A> { ... }
```

Templates use pattern matching for their parameter lists, like also seen in many functional programming languages.

> How can I test if types A and B are of the same type?

You can use `std::is_same`, or use specialization as above. It depends on your exact use case.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the types are the same using:

```
std::is_same<A, B>::value
```

it will return true when they are.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct EnsureSameType {};

template <typename A>
struct EnsureSameType<A, A> {
    typedef int the_template_types_are_different;
};

int main()
{
    /* this should compile */
    typedef EnsureSameType<std::string::value_type, char>::the_template_types_are_different _;
    /* this should fail, and you will see the compiler
       remind you that the_template_types_are_different */
    typedef EnsureSameType<std::string::value_type, wchar_t>::the_template_types_are_different _;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really like your use of non std. One less #include I need to worry about.

Comment: Seriously? Worrying about standard library includes? You need to rethink your priorities.

Comment: @Waldermort I'm not using STL solution, just because I could only get a bool value via `std::is_same`, but your question need a compile error.

Comment: @neuront I understand. I prefer the compile error over the stl method.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Seriously? Judging without the facts? Where strings come into play I try to stay away from STL since, in my experience, every compiler is different. For example ASCII vs UTF8 std::string.

Comment: @Waldermort Worrying about string representation is one thing. Worrying about "an include" is another.